# Changing the shape of different groups within a column using geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am trying to create a geom_point graph and within a column, I have different groups. I want each group to be represented in a different way, e.g. A - Square, B - Triangle etc. Is there any way to do this?

Sample of table

| Treatment | Time period | No. of blooms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | One | 67 |
| B | One | 137 |
| C | One | 32 |
| A | Two | 118 |
| B | Two | 212 |
| C | Two | 18 |

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use the argument `shape = Treatment` inside `aes()`? *E.g.* `geom_point(aes(..., shape = Treatment))`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by mapping on the `shape` aes. If you want to assign specific shapes to categories you have to do that manually using `scale_shape_manual`. For a list of available shapes see 
[Aesthetic specifications](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#point).

```r
df <- data.frame(
         Treatment = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
       Time.period = c("One", "One", "One", "Two", "Two", "Two"),
     No..of.blooms = c(67L, 137L, 32L, 118L, 212L, 18L)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Time.period, No..of.blooms, shape = Treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(A = 15, B = 17, C = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I managed to use scale_shape_manual() to change the shapes as I wanted

Comment: Say both treatment A and B do the same thing in time period one, is there anyway to group them within ggplot so they appear under the same legend item

Comment: @Rachel97 if you want to do it manually you could do `scale_shape_manual(values = c(A = 15, B = 15, C = 16))`. Otherwise you might need to create a new goupping column in your data.